# My program only runs in debug mode (visual Studio 2010)

Tags: visual-studio-2010

My program runs fine in debug mode but crashes in release mode, I have read a similar question and someone said it might be an uninitialized variable but ive gone through the code and couldnt find any, any help?

I selected win32 console application and then empty project and console application on settings

The error happens AFTER I read both files, and before displaying the message

> "Ingrese el margen de error aceptado (numero de bits distintos con
>   respecto a la matriz final):"

Here is my code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#define cantidadDeIndividuos 100
#define cantidadDeFilas 255
#define cantidadDeColumnas 255
#define numeroDeBitsDeLaRegla 32
using namespace std;
class Matriz{
private:
    unsigned int dm;
    int f,c;
    bool** matrizDeBits;
    unsigned int resultado;
public:
    Matriz(){
        f=cantidadDeFilas;
        c=cantidadDeColumnas;
        dm=((unsigned int)f)*((unsigned int)c);
        matrizDeBits=new bool*[f];
        int cx,cy;
        for(cy=0;cy<f;cy++){
            matrizDeBits[cy]=new bool[c];
        }
        for(cy=0;cy<f;cy++){
            for(cx=0;cx<c;cx++){
                matrizDeBits[cy][cx]=false;
            }
        }
    }
    bool getBit(int i, int j){
        return matrizDeBits[i][j];
    }
    void setBit(int i, int j, bool v){
        matrizDeBits[i][j]=v;
    }
    unsigned int comparar(Matriz m1, Matriz m2){
        resultado=dm;
        int cx,cy;
        for(cy=0;cy<f;cy++){
            for(cx=0;cx<c;cx++){
                if( (m1.getBit(cy,cx)&&m2.getBit(cy,cx)) || ( (!m1.getBit(cy,cx)) && (!m2.getBit(cy,cx))) )
                    resultado--;
            }
        }
        return resultado;
    }
};
class ManejadorDeNumerosAleatorios{
public:
    ManejadorDeNumerosAleatorios(){
        srand ( (unsigned)time(NULL) );
    }
    void reInicializar(){
        srand ( (unsigned)time(NULL) );
    }
    bool* obtenerReglaAleatoria(){
        bool* resultado=new bool[numeroDeBitsDeLaRegla];
        int contador=0;
        int numeroAleatorio; // entre 0 y rand_max, el cual es 32768 (2^15)
        do{
            numeroAleatorio=rand();
            while(numeroAleatorio>0){
                if( (numeroAleatorio%2) == 1)
                    resultado[contador]=true;
                else
                    resultado[contador]=false;
                numeroAleatorio/=2;
                contador++;
            }
        }while(contador<numeroDeBitsDeLaRegla);
        return resultado;
    } 
    short obtenerIteraciones(int maximo){
        return ((short)(rand()%maximo));
    }
};
class ManejadorDeArchivos{
private:
    bool seHaLeidoArchivoDeEntrada;
    bool seHaLeidoArchivoDeSalida;
    Matriz datosDeEntrada;
    Matriz datosDeSalida;
public:
    ManejadorDeArchivos(){
        seHaLeidoArchivoDeEntrada=false;
        seHaLeidoArchivoDeSalida=false;
    }
    bool noSeHanLeidoLosArchivosNecesarios(){
        if(seHaLeidoArchivoDeEntrada&&seHaLeidoArchivoDeSalida)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
    Matriz obtenerDatosDeEntrada(){
        return datosDeEntrada;
    }
    Matriz obtenerDatosDeSalida(){
        return datosDeSalida;
    }
    void leerArchivoDeEntrada(){
        char nombre[100];
        cout<<endl<<"Ingrese el nombre del archivo de entrada: ";
        gets(nombre);
        ifstream lectura(nombre,ios::beg);
        if(!lectura||lectura.bad()){
            cout<<"No se ha podido Abrir el archivo, verifique que el nombre sea correcto y que este en la misma carpeta donde se encuentra este ejecutable";
            return;
        }
        char* miLineaLeida=new char[(cantidadDeColumnas+1)];
        int contadorDeLineas,cj;
        for(contadorDeLineas=0;!lectura.eof();contadorDeLineas++){
            if(contadorDeLineas==cantidadDeFilas){
                cout<<endl<<"Se han leido correctamente "<<cantidadDeFilas<<" filas del archivo";
                break;
            }
            lectura>>miLineaLeida;
            for(cj=0;miLineaLeida[cj]!='\0';cj++){
                if(cj==cantidadDeColumnas){
                    cout<<endl<<"Se ha encontrado una fila que contiene mas de "<<cantidadDeColumnas<<" elementos, lectura fallida. Por favor verifique el contenido del archivo de entrada.";
                    return;
                }
                if(miLineaLeida[cj]=='1')
                    datosDeEntrada.setBit(contadorDeLineas,cj,true);
                else if(miLineaLeida[cj]!='0'){
                    cout<<"Se ha encontrado un caracter distinto de <<1>> o <<0>>";
                    return;
                }   
            }
            if(cj<cantidadDeColumnas){
                cout<<"Se ha encontrado una fila con menos caracteres de lo esperado ("<<cantidadDeColumnas<<")";
                return;
            }
        }
        lectura.close();
        if(contadorDeLineas<cantidadDeFilas){
            cout<<"Se ha encontrado una cantidad de lineas menor de lo esperado ("<<cantidadDeFilas<<")";
            return;
        }
        seHaLeidoArchivoDeEntrada=true;
        cout<<endl<<"Lectura Exitosa";
    }
    void leerArchivoDeSalida(){
        char nombre[100];
        cout<<endl<<"Ingrese el nombre del archivo de salida: ";
        gets(nombre);
        ifstream lectura(nombre,ios::beg);
        if(!lectura||lectura.bad()){
            cout<<"No se ha podido Abrir el archivo, verifique que el nombre sea correcto y que este en la misma carpeta donde se encuentra este ejecutable";
            return;
        }
        char* miLineaLeida=new char[(cantidadDeColumnas+1)];
        int contadorDeLineas,cj;
        for(contadorDeLineas=0;!lectura.eof();contadorDeLineas++){
            if(contadorDeLineas==cantidadDeFilas){
                cout<<endl<<"Se han leido correctamente "<<cantidadDeFilas<<" filas del archivo";
                break;
            }
            lectura>>miLineaLeida;
            for(cj=0;miLineaLeida[cj]!='\0';cj++){
                if(cj==cantidadDeColumnas){
                    cout<<endl<<"Se ha encontrado una fila que contiene mas de "<<cantidadDeColumnas<<" elementos, lectura fallida. Por favor verifique el contenido del archivo de entrada.";
                    return;
                }
                if(miLineaLeida[cj]=='1')
                    datosDeSalida.setBit(contadorDeLineas,cj,true);
                else if(miLineaLeida[cj]!='0'){
                    cout<<"Se ha encontrado un caracter distinto de <<1>> o <<0>>";
                    return;
                }   
            }
            if(cj<cantidadDeColumnas){
                cout<<"Se ha encontrado una fila con menos caracteres de lo esperado ("<<cantidadDeColumnas<<")";
                return;
            }
        }
        lectura.close();
        if(contadorDeLineas<cantidadDeFilas){
            cout<<"Se ha encontrado una cantidad de lineas menor de lo esperado ("<<cantidadDeFilas<<")";
            return;
        }
        seHaLeidoArchivoDeSalida=true;
        cout<<endl<<"Lectura Exitosa";
    }
};
class Individuo{
private:
    bool regla[3][32];
    short iteraciones[3];
    unsigned int distancia;
public:
    Individuo(){
    }
    void inicializarIndividuo(bool* r1, bool* r2, bool* r3, short i1, short i2, short i3){
        distancia=0;
        int contador;
        for(contador=0;contador<32;contador++) regla[0][contador]=*(r1+contador);
        for(contador=0;contador<32;contador++) regla[1][contador]=*(r2+contador);
        for(contador=0;contador<32;contador++) regla[2][contador]=*(r3+contador);
        iteraciones[0]=i1;
        iteraciones[1]=i2;
        iteraciones[2]=i3;
    }
    bool* getRegla(int numeroDeRegla){
        return regla[numeroDeRegla];
    }
    bool getBit(int numeroDeRegla, int posicionEnLaRegla){
        return regla[numeroDeRegla][posicionEnLaRegla];
    }
    short getIteracionesDeRegla(int numeroDeRegla){
        return iteraciones[numeroDeRegla];
    }
    void setDistancia(unsigned int d){
        distancia=d;
    }
    unsigned int getDistancia(){
        return distancia;
    }
    void mutar(int reglaElegida, int posicionDeBitEnLaRegla, int nuevoNumeroDeIteraciones){
        regla[reglaElegida][posicionDeBitEnLaRegla]=!regla[reglaElegida][posicionDeBitEnLaRegla];
        iteraciones[reglaElegida]=(short)nuevoNumeroDeIteraciones;
    }
};
//Dentro de la clase poblacion se manejaran los mecanismos de seleccion de individuos para la reproduccion, y evolucion
class Poblacion{
private:
    Matriz matrizInicial,matrizFinal,matrizParaIrAplicandoReglas,matrizParaIrAplicandoReglas2;
    Individuo poblacionActual[cantidadDeIndividuos],proximaPoblacion[cantidadDeIndividuos];
    ManejadorDeNumerosAleatorios mna;
    int posicionEnFila,posicionEnColumna,posicionDeBitEnRegla;
    int contadorRegla,contadorIteracionesDeRegla;
    int sumatoria;
    int margenDeErrorAceptado;
public:
    bool solucionEncontrada;
    Individuo solucion;
    Poblacion(Matriz mi, Matriz mf){
        mna.reInicializar();
        solucionEncontrada=false;
        margenDeErrorAceptado=0;
        matrizInicial=mi;
        matrizFinal=mf;
        int ci;
        for(ci=0;ci<cantidadDeIndividuos;ci++){
            poblacionActual[ci].inicializarIndividuo( mna.obtenerReglaAleatoria(),mna.obtenerReglaAleatoria(),mna.obtenerReglaAleatoria(),
                                               mna.obtenerIteraciones(8),mna.obtenerIteraciones(8),mna.obtenerIteraciones(8) );
            proximaPoblacion[ci]=poblacionActual[ci];
        }
        calcularSumatoria();
    }
    void evaluarIndividuos(){
        int contadorDeIndividuo,f=cantidadDeFilas,c=cantidadDeColumnas;
        for(contadorDeIndividuo=0;contadorDeIndividuo<cantidadDeIndividuos;contadorDeIndividuo++){ // para cada individuo
            matrizParaIrAplicandoReglas=matrizInicial;
            for(contadorRegla=0;contadorRegla<3;contadorRegla++){ // para aplicar las 3 reglas
                for(contadorIteracionesDeRegla=0;contadorIteracionesDeRegla<poblacionActual[contadorDeIndividuo].getIteracionesDeRegla(contadorRegla);contadorIteracionesDeRegla++){ // para aplicar una regla varias veces
                    for(posicionEnFila=0;posicionEnFila<f;posicionEnFila++){ // para ir recorriendo las filas de la matriz
                        for(posicionEnColumna=0;posicionEnColumna<c;posicionEnColumna++){ // para ir recorriendo las columnas y aplicar la regla
                            posicionDeBitEnRegla=0;
                            if( matrizParaIrAplicandoReglas.getBit( ( (f+posicionEnFila-1)%f) , ((c+posicionEnColumna-1)%c) ) )
                                posicionDeBitEnRegla+=1;
                            if( matrizParaIrAplicandoReglas.getBit( ( (f+posicionEnFila-1)%f) , ((posicionEnColumna+1)%c) ) )
                                posicionDeBitEnRegla+=2;
                            if( matrizParaIrAplicandoReglas.getBit( ( (posicionEnFila+1)%f) , ((posicionEnColumna+1)%c) ) )
                                posicionDeBitEnRegla+=4;
                            if( matrizParaIrAplicandoReglas.getBit( ( (posicionEnFila+1)%f) , ((c+posicionEnColumna-1)%c) ) )
                                posicionDeBitEnRegla+=8;
                            if( matrizParaIrAplicandoReglas.getBit( posicionEnFila, posicionEnColumna ) )
                                posicionDeBitEnRegla+=16;
                            if(poblacionActual[contadorDeIndividuo].getBit(contadorRegla,posicionDeBitEnRegla))
                                matrizParaIrAplicandoReglas2.setBit(posicionEnFila,posicionEnColumna,true);
                            else
                                matrizParaIrAplicandoReglas2.setBit(posicionEnFila,posicionEnColumna,false);
                        }//FIN del for para recorrer columnas
                    }// FIN del for para recorrer filas
                    matrizParaIrAplicandoReglas=matrizParaIrAplicandoReglas2;
                }// FIN del for para aplicar 1 de las reglas varias veces
            } // FIN del for de las 3 reglas de cada individuo
            poblacionActual[contadorDeIndividuo].setDistancia(matrizFinal.comparar(matrizParaIrAplicandoReglas,matrizFinal));
            if(poblacionActual[contadorDeIndividuo].getDistancia()<=(unsigned int)margenDeErrorAceptado){
                solucion=poblacionActual[contadorDeIndividuo];
                solucionEncontrada=true;
                return;
            }
        } // FIN del for para cada individuo
    }// FIN de la funcion EVALUAR_INDIVIDUOS

    //La funcion emplea el algoritmo de ordenacion por insercion, no recomendable para poblaciones mayores a 4000
    //El primer elemento tiene la mayor distancia de hamming, por lo tanto es el menos deseable
    void ordenarIndividuos(){
        int i,j;
        Individuo auxiliar;
        for(i=1;i<cantidadDeIndividuos;i++){
            j=i;
            auxiliar=poblacionActual[i];
            while(j>0&&auxiliar.getDistancia()>poblacionActual[j-1].getDistancia()){
                poblacionActual[j]=poblacionActual[j-1];
                j--;
            }
            poblacionActual[j]=auxiliar;
        }
    }

    //El objetivo de esta funcion es poder trabajar con numeros enteros, evitando asi las operaciones de coma flotante que son
    //mucho mas lentas.
    void calcularSumatoria(){
        long sum;
        int contador;
        for(contador=1,sum=0L;contador<=cantidadDeIndividuos;contador++){
            sum+=(long)contador;
            if(sum>=RAND_MAX){
                sumatoria=RAND_MAX;
                return;
            }
        }
        sumatoria=(int)sum;
    }

    //el primer padre es elegido aleatoriamente de una sola vez
    // mientras que el segundo debera superar la probabilidad
    void evolucionar(){
        int contadorDeIndividuo,primerPadre,segundoPadre,probabilidadAleatoria;
        for(contadorDeIndividuo=0;contadorDeIndividuo<cantidadDeIndividuos;contadorDeIndividuo++){ //Generacion de cada individuo
            primerPadre=rand()%cantidadDeIndividuos;
            do{
                segundoPadre=rand()%cantidadDeIndividuos;
                probabilidadAleatoria=rand()%sumatoria;
            }while(probabilidadAleatoria>segundoPadre || primerPadre==segundoPadre);
            //Una vez determinados ambos padres, determinaremos la forma en que se heredaran los cromosomas
            //Generaremos un numero [0,7] y luego de acuerdo a su forma en binario tendremos 3 bits
            //El primer bit encendido indica que heredara el primer cromosoma del primer padre, en caso contrario
            //lo heredara del segundo padre. De igual manera se toma la desicion con respecto al 2do y 3er cromosoma
            probabilidadAleatoria=rand()%8;
            if(probabilidadAleatoria==0){
                proximaPoblacion[contadorDeIndividuo]=poblacionActual[segundoPadre];
            }
            else if(probabilidadAleatoria==1){
                proximaPoblacion[contadorDeIndividuo].inicializarIndividuo(poblacionActual[primerPadre].getRegla(0),
                                                                           poblacionActual[segundoPadre].getRegla(1),
                                                                           poblacionActual[segundoPadre].getRegla(2),
                                                                           poblacionActual[primerPadre].getIteracionesDeRegla(0),
                                                                           poblacionActual[segundoPadre].getIteracionesDeRegla(1),
                                                                           poblacionActual[segundoPadre].getIteracionesDeRegla(2));
            }
            else if(probabilidadAleatoria==2){
                proximaPoblacion[contadorDeIndividuo].inicializarIndividuo(poblacionActual[segundoPadre].getRegla(0),
                                                                           poblacionActual[primerPadre].getRegla(1),
                                                                           poblacionActual[segundoPadre].getRegla(2),
                                                                           poblacionActual[segundoPadre].getIteracionesDeRegla(0),
                                                                           poblacionActual[primerPadre].getIteracionesDeRegla(1),
                                                                           poblacionActual[segundoPadre].getIteracionesDeRegla(2));
            }
            else if(probabilidadAleatoria==3){
                proximaPoblacion[contadorDeIndividuo].inicializarIndividuo(poblacionActual[primerPadre].getRegla(0),
                                                                           poblacionActual[primerPadre].getRegla(1),
                                                                           poblacionActual[segundoPadre].getRegla(2),
                                                                           poblacionActual[primerPadre].getIteracionesDeRegla(0),
                                                                           poblacionActual[primerPadre].getIteracionesDeRegla(1),
                                                                           poblacionActual[segundoPadre].getIteracionesDeRegla(2));
            }
            else if(probabilidadAleatoria==4){
                proximaPoblacion[contadorDeIndividuo].inicializarIndividuo(poblacionActual[segundoPadre].getRegla(0),
                                                                           poblacionActual[segundoPadre].getRegla(1),
                                                                           poblacionActual[primerPadre].getRegla(2),
                                                                           poblacionActual[segundoPadre].getIteracionesDeRegla(0),
                                                                           poblacionActual[segundoPadre].getIteracionesDeRegla(1),
                                                                           poblacionActual[primerPadre].getIteracionesDeRegla(2));
            }
            else if(probabilidadAleatoria==5){
                proximaPoblacion[contadorDeIndividuo].inicializarIndividuo(poblacionActual[primerPadre].getRegla(0),
                                                                           poblacionActual[segundoPadre].getRegla(1),
                                                                           poblacionActual[primerPadre].getRegla(2),
                                                                           poblacionActual[primerPadre].getIteracionesDeRegla(0),
                                                                           poblacionActual[segundoPadre].getIteracionesDeRegla(1),
                                                                           poblacionActual[primerPadre].getIteracionesDeRegla(2));
            }
            else if(probabilidadAleatoria==6){
                proximaPoblacion[contadorDeIndividuo].inicializarIndividuo(poblacionActual[segundoPadre].getRegla(0),
                                                                           poblacionActual[primerPadre].getRegla(1),
                                                                           poblacionActual[primerPadre].getRegla(2),
                                                                           poblacionActual[segundoPadre].getIteracionesDeRegla(0),
                                                                           poblacionActual[primerPadre].getIteracionesDeRegla(1),
                                                                           poblacionActual[primerPadre].getIteracionesDeRegla(2));
            }
            else{
                proximaPoblacion[contadorDeIndividuo]=poblacionActual[primerPadre];
            }
            //Aqui se trata la posibilidad de que haya una mutacion, en un bit y/o en las iteraciones, la probabilidad es 1/1000
            probabilidadAleatoria=rand()%1000;
            if(probabilidadAleatoria==212){
                proximaPoblacion[contadorDeIndividuo].mutar( (rand()%3), (rand()%31), (rand()%8) );
            }
        }//Fin del for de generacion de cada individuo
        //Ahora esta poblacion generada se convierte en la poblacionActual
        for(contadorDeIndividuo=0;contadorDeIndividuo<cantidadDeIndividuos;contadorDeIndividuo++){
            poblacionActual[contadorDeIndividuo]=proximaPoblacion[contadorDeIndividuo];
        }
    }
    Individuo obtenerMejorIndividuo(){
        return poblacionActual[cantidadDeIndividuos-1];
    }
    void setMargenDeError(int margen){
        margenDeErrorAceptado=margen;
    }
};
//Los siguientes metodos solo sirven con reglas de 32 bits
class HerramientasDePrueba{
public:
    HerramientasDePrueba(){
    }
    /*static bool* LONG_to_BOOL_ARRAY(unsigned long x){
        bool* resultado=new bool[32];
        unsigned long valor=x;
        int contador;
        for(contador=0;contador<31;contador++,valor/=2L){
            if(valor%2L==1L){
                resultado[contador]=true;
            }
            else{
                resultado[contador]=false;
            }
        }
    }
    static char* BOOL_ARRAY_to_STRING(bool* boolarray, int arraylenght){
        char* resultado=new char[arraylenght+1];
        int contador;
        for(contador=0;contador<arraylenght;contador++){
            if(boolarray[contador]){
                resultado[contador]='1';
            }
            else{
                resultado[contador]='0';
            }
        }
        resultado[contador]='\0';
        return resultado;
    }*/
    static unsigned long BOOL_ARRAY_to_LONG(bool* boolarray, int arraylenght){
        int contador;
        unsigned long resultado=0L;
        for(contador=0;contador<arraylenght;contador++){
            if(boolarray[contador])
                resultado+=(unsigned long)pow(2.0,(double)contador);
        }
        return resultado;
    }
    static void mostrarResultado(Individuo r){
        if(r.getDistancia()==0){
            cout<<endl<<"Se ha encontrada la respuesta EXACTA: ";
        }
        else{
            cout<<endl<<"Se ha encontrada una respuesta aceptable: ";
        }
        cout<<endl<<" Regla 1:"<<BOOL_ARRAY_to_LONG(r.getRegla(0),32)<<" Aplicada: "<<r.getIteracionesDeRegla(0)<<" veces";
        cout<<endl<<" Regla 2:"<<BOOL_ARRAY_to_LONG(r.getRegla(1),32)<<" Aplicada: "<<r.getIteracionesDeRegla(1)<<" veces";
        cout<<endl<<" Regla 3:"<<BOOL_ARRAY_to_LONG(r.getRegla(2),32)<<" Aplicada: "<<r.getIteracionesDeRegla(2)<<" veces";
    }
    static void mostrarMejorIndividuo(Individuo r, int i){
        cout<<"Datos del mejor individuo de la iteracion #"<<i<<": ";
        cout<<endl<<"Distancia: "<<r.getDistancia();
        cout<<endl<<" Regla 1:"<<BOOL_ARRAY_to_LONG(r.getRegla(0),32)<<" Aplicada: "<<r.getIteracionesDeRegla(0)<<" veces";
        cout<<endl<<" Regla 2:"<<BOOL_ARRAY_to_LONG(r.getRegla(1),32)<<" Aplicada: "<<r.getIteracionesDeRegla(1)<<" veces";
        cout<<endl<<" Regla 3:"<<BOOL_ARRAY_to_LONG(r.getRegla(2),32)<<" Aplicada: "<<r.getIteracionesDeRegla(2)<<" veces";
    }
};
void main(){
    string z="\nMenu:\n1.Leer Archivo de entrada\n2.Leer Archivo de salida\n3.Ejecutar Algoritmo Genetico\n0.Salir\nOpcion Seleccionada: ";
    char opcion[20];
    int accion=10;
    ManejadorDeArchivos archivos;
    do{
        puts(z.c_str());
        gets(opcion);
        try{
            accion=atoi(opcion);
        }
        catch(exception e){
            cout<<"Seleccion no valida";
            continue;
        }
        if(accion==1){
            archivos.leerArchivoDeEntrada();
        }
        else if(accion==2){
            archivos.leerArchivoDeSalida();
        }
        else if(accion==3){
            if(archivos.noSeHanLeidoLosArchivosNecesarios()){
                cout<<endl<<"Se debe haber leido correctamente el archivo de entrada(matriz inicial) y el archivo de salida(matriz final) para poder continuar";
                continue;
            }
            Poblacion p(archivos.obtenerDatosDeEntrada(),archivos.obtenerDatosDeSalida());
            int numeroDeIteracionesRestantes=0,iteracionesTotales=1,margenError;
            cout<<endl<<"Ingrese el margen de error aceptado (numero de bits distintos con respecto a la matriz final): ";
            cin>>margenError;
            p.setMargenDeError(margenError);
            do{
                p.evaluarIndividuos();
                if(p.solucionEncontrada){
                    HerramientasDePrueba::mostrarResultado(p.solucion);
                    cout<<"Programa Finalizado";
                    cin.get();
                    return;
                }
                p.ordenarIndividuos();
                HerramientasDePrueba::mostrarMejorIndividuo(p.obtenerMejorIndividuo(),iteracionesTotales);
                p.evolucionar();
                if(numeroDeIteracionesRestantes==0){
                    cout<<endl<<"Cuantas Iteraciones mas desea ejecutar antes de terminar el programa (en caso de no encontrar la respuesta exacta)? ingrese 0 en caso de no querer ejecutar mas iteraciones: ";
                    cin>>numeroDeIteracionesRestantes;
                }
            numeroDeIteracionesRestantes--;
            iteracionesTotales++;
            }while(numeroDeIteracionesRestantes>0);
        }
        else if(accion!=0){
            cout<<endl<<"Por favor seleccione una opcion correcta.";
        }
    }while(accion!=0);
    cout<<"Programa Finalizado";
    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: If you paste a source code it could help us to help you.

Comment: I suggest you copy your code into this question.  A lot of people are going to be reluctant to, or just not bother downloading an anonymous file from a random file sharing site

Comment: why don't you look at the crash information or at least post it

Comment: i just added the code, sorry for not posting it first, i didnt think ppl wouldnt download a .cpp xD

Answer (score 0):

First of all your main should be `int main` not `void main`. Now to get onto the actual problems, we can perform some static analysis on your code:

```
1>ClCompile:
1>  test.cpp
1>c:\users\mike\desktop\test\test\test.cpp(106): warning C4996: 'gets': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using gets_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\stdio.h(277) : see declaration of 'gets'
1>c:\users\mike\desktop\test\test\test.cpp(148): warning C4996: 'gets': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using gets_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\stdio.h(277) : see declaration of 'gets'
1>c:\users\mike\desktop\test\test\test.cpp(475): warning C4996: 'gets': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using gets_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\stdio.h(277) : see declaration of 'gets'
1>c:\users\mike\desktop\test\test\test.cpp(106): warning C6202: Buffer overrun for 'nombre', which is possibly stack allocated, in call to 'gets': length '4294967295' exceeds buffer size '100'
1>c:\users\mike\desktop\test\test\test.cpp(106): warning C6386: Buffer overrun: accessing 'argument 1', the writable size is '100' bytes, but '4294967295' bytes might be written: Lines: 104, 105, 106
1>c:\users\mike\desktop\test\test\test.cpp(148): warning C6202: Buffer overrun for 'nombre', which is possibly stack allocated, in call to 'gets': length '4294967295' exceeds buffer size '100'
1>c:\users\mike\desktop\test\test\test.cpp(148): warning C6386: Buffer overrun: accessing 'argument 1', the writable size is '100' bytes, but '4294967295' bytes might be written: Lines: 146, 147, 148
1>c:\users\mike\desktop\test\test\test.cpp(348): warning C6386: Buffer overrun: accessing 'poblacionActual', the writable size is '10800' bytes, but '47844' bytes might be written: Lines: 324, 325, 326, 328, 329, 330, 335, 336, 339, 347, 348
1>c:\users\mike\desktop\test\test\test.cpp(337): warning C6385: Invalid data: accessing 'poblacionActual', the readable size is '10800' bytes, but '47844' bytes might be read: Lines: 324, 325, 326, 328, 329, 330, 335, 336, 339, 347, 348, 391, 392, 325, 326, 328, 329, 330, 335, 336, 337
1>c:\users\mike\desktop\test\test\test.cpp(468): warning C6262: Function uses '21936' bytes of stack: exceeds /analyze:stacksize'16384'. Consider moving some data to heap
1>c:\users\mike\desktop\test\test\test.cpp(475): warning C6202: Buffer overrun for 'opcion', which is possibly stack allocated, in call to 'gets': length '4294967295' exceeds buffer size '20'
1>c:\users\mike\desktop\test\test\test.cpp(475): warning C6386: Buffer overrun: accessing 'argument 1', the writable size is '20' bytes, but '4294967295' bytes might be written: Lines: 469, 470, 471, 472, 474, 475
```

I suppose you should start by fixing all of these. As you have correctly suggested, these sorts of bugs appear most of the time from the access of uninitialized data, but in this case it could well be due to the many potential buffer overruns.